# Different field name for database / schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

TL:DR; is it possible to have a field `foobarbaz` which is stored with a different name `f` in the document?

I'm currently planning a new database schema which will contain a lot of documents (expecting something between 10 and 100k documents power day). So I want to  shorten field names, since they take up space pet document.

But I want to have readable names in my schema as well. So my question is: is it possible to connect a schema field with a document field which has a different name?

schema: `name`
document: `n`

Answer (score 0):

Try [mongoose-aliasfield](https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-aliasfield)

> Plugin is intended to write short-keys for you documents on the DB but let you use long, descriptive name when reading fetched documents. This will result in less storage needed to memorize your data having no need to remember short key meanings.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fieldsAliasPlugin = require('mongoose-aliasfield');

/*Describe a Schema*/
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    't' : {'type': Date, 'index': true, 'alias': 'timestamp'},
    'n' : {'type' : String, 'alias': 'name'},
    's' : {'type' : String, 'alias': 'surname'},
    'p' : {
        'a' : {'type' : String, 'alias': 'profile.address'},
        'pn': {'type' : String, 'alias': 'profile.phone_number'}
    }
});

/*Add field alias plugin*/
PersonSchema.plugin(fieldsAliasPlugin);
```

Now that your schema is created you can use alias field name to describe an instance of your model

```
var person = new Person({
    'timestamp' : new Date(),
    'name'      : 'Jhon',
    'surname'   : 'Doe',
    'profile.address': 'Rue de Morgane',
    'profile.phone_number': '051-123456 78',
});

person.save();
```